# P2P programing in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, p2p

I am trying to explore [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Listings/AppController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007321-AppController_m-DontLinkElementID_4) application.

There is one function in Appcontroller.m

in method applicationDidFinishLaunching.

There is method name :-

```
// Create and advertise our server.  We only want the service to be registered on 
// local networks so we pass in the "local." domain.

 self.server = [[QServer alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:kWiTapBonjourType name:nil preferredPort:0];
```

My problem is I am not able to accessing Port on different server.
Please guide me what should i write in Domain and Port number.

Its showing registering.Not showing any connection.
While if i write domain and Port then it will able to make the conection to the LAN connection.

But if i write difference IP address its not able to do the connection.
It is not firing any error but not able to make the connection successfully to the server

Comment: What do you mean "not able"?  What behaviour are you seeing?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Jim I have editied my question and described it in detail.Please have a glance in that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to use this with Bluetooth.  That's not possible any more using this API.  You have to drop to a lower level.

If you read the `ReadMe.txt` file in the sample code you used, you will see:

> The version of WiTap no longer works over Bluetooth; see [QA1753 "Bonjour over Bluetooth on iOS 5.0"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1753/_index.html) for a discussion of why that's the case and what you can do about it.

If you are interested in Bluetooth P2P networking, consider using [HHServices](https://github.com/tolo/HHServices).

Comment: is there any option to use P2P programing else that bluetooth. Atully i want to work create the video sharing by P2P like we have webrtc in browser.

Comment: From the description of WiTap: *"The WiTap sample demonstrates peer-to-peer networking over Wi-Fi."*